# Hibernate complaining undefined alias. What does it mean?

Tags: hibernate

I have a table in database that doesn't have hibernate mapping onto it. And I was trying to make a query on the table using following code:

```
List theList = session().createSQLQuery("select field_A from table_A").list();
```

and I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: undefined alias: field_A [select field_A from table_A]
```

I doesn't really understand what does this mean. May I know what is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you give a description of your table? (`desc table_A` in SQL)

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem solved. The solution is like below:

```
List theList = session()
   .createSQLQuery("select * from table_A")
   .addScalar("field_A", Hibernate.STRING)
   .list();
```

This code is reference from this [Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)